# How to get content the content of a node using the QueryBuilder of Adobe Experience Manager

Tags: adobe, aem, query-builder

Let's say I have a node /etc/designs/blog/css/static.css

At the moment I only achieve to get this:

```
{
  success: true,
  results: 1,
  total: 1,
  offset: 0,
  hits: [
    {
      path: "/etc/designs/blog/css/static.css/jcr:content",
      name: "jcr:content",
      title: "jcr:content",
      lastModified: "2011-02-18 12:28:12",
      size: "12 KB",
      mimeType: "text/css"
    }
  ]
}
```

by calling this url: `http://www.example.com/bin/querybuilder.json?path=/etc/designs/blog/css/static.css`.

Is it possible to get the content of the node using the QueryBuilder?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. However, you can use the Query builder API's to iterate over the result set and perform the required operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding `p.hits=full`.  For example:

http://www.example.com/bin/querybuilder.json?p.hits=full&path=%2Fetc%2Fdesigns%2Fblog%2Fcss%2Fstatic.css

This usage is detailed here: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html#Refining%20What%20Is%20Returned  This states:

> Refining What Is Returned
>
> By default, the QueryBuilder JSON Servlet will return a default set of
>   properties for each node in the search result (e.g. path, name, title,
>   etc.). In order to gain control over which properties are returned,
>   you can do one of the following:
>
> Specify p.hits=full, in which case all properties will be included for
>   each node:
>
> http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?p.hits=full&property=jcr%3atitle&property.value=Triangle

Comment: This still doesn't return the content within the file, though it returns the length of the data available within the node for the `jcr:data` property